# How to create a transactional master table via MySQL by joining multiple separate tables on common date and product key plus specific dimensions?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, transactions

I am dealing with the following challenge:

I have multiple (sparse) tables that all share a common date field + common "product_id"s. Additionally each table has one additional field which tracks a specific kind of transactional data for the product, such as "units sold", "units purchased", "received_support_requests", etc.

Table 1

| DATE | PRODUCT ID | UNITS SOLD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 10 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2 | 40 |

Table 2

| DATE | PRODUCT ID | UNITS PURCHASED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2 | 456 |
| 2022-01-04 | 5 | 34 |

Table 3

| DATE | PRODUCT ID | RECEIVED SUPPORT REQUESTS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-04 | 5 | 2 |
| 2022-01-05 | 2 | 1 |

My **goal** is to somehow **join all of these tables** so that I get a master table which shows what happened to each product on a specific day as shown below **using MySQL**:

| DATE | PRODUCT ID | UNITS SOLD | UNITS PURCHASED | RECEIVED SUPPORT REQUESTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2 | 0 | 456 | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2 | 40 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-01-04 | 5 | 0 | 34 | 2 |
| 2022-01-05 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

The tables are all very long > 50000
and contain a big list of products > 3000

I first though about building a kind of ("date" - "product id") scaffold and then just left join all of the tables to this scaffold table. Unfortunately the combination of each date, with each product gets too big.

How would you accomplish such a join in a more efficient way?

Comment: It would probably be better not to have separate tables for everything, use a single attribute-value table.

Comment: *The tables are all very long > 50000* This is small table (even average ~ after 1kk rows).

Comment: Unfortunately the tables already come in this format from the data sources, so I can't really do anything about it. Thanks for reminding me that this is still to be considered a small table. I was referring to the cartesian product becoming quite big though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT date, 
       product_id,
       COALESCE(table1.amount, 0) sold,
       COALESCE(table2.amount, 0) purchased,
       COALESCE(table3.amount, 0) supported
FROM ( SELECT date FROM table1 
       UNION
       SELECT date FROM table2 
       UNION
       SELECT date FROM table3 ) dates
CROSS 
JOIN ( SELECT product_id FROM table1 
       UNION
       SELECT product_id FROM table2 
       UNION
       SELECT product_id FROM table3 ) products
NATURAL LEFT JOIN table1
NATURAL LEFT JOIN table2
NATURAL LEFT JOIN table3
HAVING sold + purchased + supported;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much, that actually works! I just had to change the last line to WHERE (sold != 0) OR (purchased != 0) OR (supported != 0), since HAVING produced a value error. I ve read a lot about NATURAL joins being kind of dangerous because in case the field namings change the query won't work anymore etc. Is there an alternative to using the NATURAL LEFT JOIN as well or don't you see an issue with this?